# How to read a CHAR (letter code) as an amount through input file

Tags: c++

I have a homework assignment which I am having some difficulty with because the teacher is assigning work that we haven't even fully discussed. I have some grasp on infile/outfiles, but I am having trouble on two main things:

How can I get the outfile to read my letter codes as a specific charge amount, and how can I continue the second row as a child to my first row.

Heads up, he doesn't let us use vectors and wants us using simple C++ tools.

[image: main assignment]

I've tried using if statements to check the char and if its a match, set the charge of said code and multiply to the value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    // VARIABLES
    ifstream infile;     // Input file stream
    ofstream outfile;    // Output file stream
    const double treeRemove = 300.00;
    const double treeTrim = 50.00;
    double treeStump = 20.00;
    double discount = 0.90;
    double treeStumpPlus = 2.00;
    double chargeR = 300;
    double chargeT = 50;
    //double chargeG;
    char letterCode;
    int val = 0, recNum = 0, i = 0;       // All ints declared
    double total = 0;      // Totals as a double (incase of decimal)

    // Open infile, if issues show error
    infile.open("C:\\temp\\infile.txt");
    if (!infile.is_open()) {
        cout << "Could not open file: 'infile.txt'" << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 1; // Error return
    }

    // Open outfile
    outfile.open("C:\\temp\\outfile.txt");

    // Header
    outfile << "Orlando Tree Service Totals" << endl << endl;

    // Prime
    infile >> letterCode >> val;

    // Start out infile check and while loop.. Clear up the int values

    while (infile) {
        val = 0;
        chargeR = 0;
        chargeT = 0;
        total = 0;

        for (i = 0;  i < 4; ++i) {

            if (letterCode == 'R') {
                chargeR = val * treeRemove;
            }

            if (letterCode == 'T') {
                chargeT = val * treeTrim;
            }

            total = chargeR + chargeT;
            infile >> letterCode >> val;
        }

        ++recNum; // Increase record num by 1

                  // Write to file
        outfile << "Record #" << recNum << "... Tree Removal: " << chargeR << " Tree Trim " << chargeT << " Total: " << total << endl;
    }

    // Done with file, so close it

    outfile.close();
    infile.close();

    cout << "Done! Please check the output file to verify..." << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Current input file:

```
R  7  T  6.5
R  0  T  2.0
R  3  T  0
R  1  T  0
R  0  T  0
R  2  T  7.5
```

Current output file:

```
Orlando Tree Service Totals

Record #1... Tree Removal: 0 Tree Trim 300 Total: 300
Record #2... Tree Removal: 900 Tree Trim 0 Total: 900
Record #3... Tree Removal: 0 Tree Trim 0 Total: 0
Record #4... Tree Removal: 0 Tree Trim 350 Total: 350
```

As you can see the results aren't generating properly, I thought it had to do with my for statement but I don't see an issue there?

EDIT: I showed the rest of my code just for clarification

EDIT: Updated code with bracket fix to make outfile come alive.

Comment: `infile >> letterCode, val;` reads letterCode, then evaluates val. You probably meant to write `infile >> letterCode >> val;`

Comment: Yeah, I get what you are saying. So the second way you have it would make it read letter code, then read a val. In general this makes more sense but still don't get anything back on my output file.

Comment: That output statement should run exactly once per iteration of the while loop. The fact that it didn't implies that `infile` evaluated to false on the first pass, which means the read on it before the loop failed. Are you sure the contents/location of the input file are correct?

Comment: @CruzJean Yeah an outfile is being created, but only the header is being printed out. As of now I'm only using two letter codes, R and T, to try and make it work in a simpler way before expanding to the third code and my infile has all required info

Comment: Ok I did some bracket fixing that I noticed and have updated my code.. I'm finally getting a response from my outfile but it isn't exactly how I want it lol. I'll post my output file in the OP also

Comment: @JordanS What is the expected output?

Comment: @abhi312 I've posted my answer in the answer section, thanks either way!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I have figured out the solution myself and that is by using switch statements that update the price of each situation.

Will post the code here as an edit shortly in case anyone else runs into this problem!

EDIT: It only worked for one input line for some reason..

EDIT2: Got it!!

EDIT3: Almost got it that is...

EDIT4: Ok now I got it :)

Current code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;
    char letterCode;
    double tree = 0, trim = 0, stump = 0, diameter = 0, cost = 0; // Doubles (incase decimal)
    double sum, i = 0, recNum = 0; // Doubles (incase decimal)
    double totalTree, totalTrim, totalStump;

    // Open infile, if issues show error
    infile.open("C:\\temp\\infile.txt");
    if (!infile.is_open()) {
        cout << "Could not open file: 'infile.txt'" << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 1; // Error return
    }

    // Open outfile
    outfile.open("C:\\temp\\outfile.txt");
    // Header
    outfile << "Orlando Tree Service Totals" << endl;
    outfile << "----------------------------------" << endl << endl;


    // Start out infile check and while loop.. Clear up the int values
    while (infile) {

        infile >> letterCode;

        switch (letterCode) {
        case 'R': {
            infile >> tree;
            totalTree = tree * 300;
            outfile << "Tree removal cost: $" << totalTree << "\n";
            break;
        }
        case 'T': {
            infile >> trim;
            totalTrim = trim * 50;
            outfile << "Trimming cost: $" << totalTrim << "\n";

            break;
        }
        case 'G': {
            infile >> stump;
            totalStump = stump * 20;
            for (i = 0; i < stump; i++) {

                infile >> diameter;

                if (diameter > 10) {
                    totalStump = totalStump + 2;
                }
            }
            outfile << "Stump grinding cost: $" << totalStump << "\n";

            if ((totalTree + totalTrim + totalStump) > 1000) {
                outfile << "10% Discount: $" << ((totalTree + totalTrim + totalStump) * 0.10) << "\n";
                outfile << "Total cost : $" << ((totalTree + totalTrim + totalStump) * 0.90) << "\n\n";
            }

            else {
                outfile << "Total cost : $" << totalTree + totalTrim + totalStump << "\n\n";
            }
            break;
        }
        }

    }

    infile.close();
    outfile.close();

    cout << "Done! Please check the output file to verify..." << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Output file:

```
Orlando Tree Service Totals
----------------------------------

Tree removal cost: $2100
Trimming cost: $325
Stump grinding cost: $172
10% Discount: $259.7
Total cost : $2337.3

Tree removal cost: $0
Trimming cost: $100
Stump grinding cost: $20
Total cost : $120

Tree removal cost: $900
Trimming cost: $0
Stump grinding cost: $0
Total cost : $900

Tree removal cost: $300
Trimming cost: $0
Stump grinding cost: $84
Total cost : $384

Tree removal cost: $0
Trimming cost: $0
Stump grinding cost: $64
Total cost : $64

Tree removal cost: $600
Trimming cost: $375
Stump grinding cost: $42
10% Discount: $101.7
Total cost : $915.3
```